# Как считать время проведенное в сети | Discord py

Tags: discord.py, время

нужна помощь в составление кода, чтоб узнать сколько человек провел времени в сети.
Ставя статус в "сети", начинает считать время, после выхода, перестает, и чтоб узнать время нахождение в сети, нужно ввести команду в чат, как то так)))

Comment: Наверное, проще запоминать время, когда пользователь вошел в сеть, а затем, когда его статус меняется, вычитать из текущего времени то, которое запомнили. И получим точное время, сколько юзер был вести, без лишней нагрузки